# Proof of the polar decomposition

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $M$ is a von Neumann algebra and $\phi\in M_{*}$, then there exists a unique partial isometry $v\in M$ and a positive linear functional $\psi\in M_{*}$ such that $\phi=v \psi$ and $v^*v=s(\phi)$, where $s(\phi)$ is a support projection of $\phi$.

For the proof, I met with troubles. I found a reference book, it says that "if $\phi\in M_{*}$, there exists $a\in M$ with $\|a\|\leq 1$ such that $\phi(a)=\|\phi\|$". How to prove the above statement.

I have another question about support projections of a state. If $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are two states of a von Neumann algebra such that $s(\phi_1)s(\phi_2)=0$, does there exist relationships between two states

Comment: For the proof part of your question: that's a standard corollary to the Hahn-Banach theorem that you'll find in just about every beginning Functional Analysis text book.

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi=v\psi$?

Comment: @Aweygan: it's standard notation for the functional $x\longmapsto \psi(vx)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a direct consequence of the following standard result:

> **Result:** If $X$ is normed space and $x\in X$, then $$\|x\|=\max\{|\varphi(x)|:\ \varphi\in X^*,\ \|\varphi\|=1\}.$$

Apply this to $X=M_*$ and $X^*=M$.

For your second question, I don't really know what kind of relation you expect.

Comment: I have a question:  According to the above corollary, if $\phi \in M_{*} $ , there exists $a\in M$ with $\|a\| \leq 1$ such that $a(\phi)=\|\phi\|$. I felt confused about the notation, if we let $\hat{x} \in X^{**},$ we can define $\hat{x}(f)=f(x)$, where $f\in X^*$. But in this place, how to identify $a(\phi)$ with $\phi(a)$?

Comment: That's precisely how you embed $X$ in $X^{**}$. But that has nothing to do with your question nor my answer.

Comment: I mean "accrdimg to above corollary , we shoud have $\|\phi\|=a(\phi)$.

Comment: What do you mean, then, when you say that $M_*$ is the *predual* of $M$?

Comment: I mean that if we let $X=M_{*}$, if $\phi \in X$ , then $\|\phi\|=max\{\varphi(\phi): \varphi \in X^*=M, \|\varphi\|=1\}$. Then there exists $a\in M $ with $\|a\|=1$ such that $\|\phi\|=a(\phi)$.

Comment: Yes. And in what sense is an element on $M$ a functional on $M_*$?

Comment: But the above proof is :$\phi(a)=\|\phi\|$, not $\|\phi\|=a(\phi)$.

Comment: Professor Argerami, does the following relation hold: $\phi(a)=a(\phi)$?

Comment: Yes, that a way that an element $a\in M$ can be in the dual of $M_*$.